Law of the areas (2nd of Keplero) proof
I was reading the following proof of the law of the areas (the generalization for central forces):

Consider a plane curve $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$, that in polar coordinates is given by $t\mapsto \rho(t)(\cos \theta(t),\sin\theta(t))$. Since we have that $m\rho^2\dot{\theta}=c\neq 0$ (this follows from the conservation of angular momentum, but is not important to elaborate on that), then $\theta$ is monotone since $c$ is constant, and so we can use $\theta$ as an independent variable for $\rho$, and we can write it as $\rho(\theta)$.
This implies that the area function of the polar sector between $\theta_0$ and $\theta$ is given by
$$a(\theta)=\int_{\theta_0}^\theta \int_0^{\rho(\theta ')}\rho'd\rho'd\theta '=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta_0}^\theta \rho(\theta ')^2d\theta '$$
So we can define $\tilde{a}(t):=a(\theta(t))$ and obtain that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{a}(t)=\frac{d}{d\theta}a(\theta)\dot{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\rho^2\dot{\theta}$$
And we have that this quantity is constant using again the conservation of angular momentum $m\rho^2\dot{\theta}=c$.

My question is, why the bold part is true? What is the implication? It seems to me that the only reasonable way to define $\rho$ as a function of $\theta$ is $\rho(\theta):=\rho(t)$ where $t$ satisfies $\theta(t)=\theta$, but why can we do this and why it is related to the fact that $\theta$ is monotone?

The relation $m\rho^2\dot\theta =c\ne 0$ is written mathematically, i guess so,$$m;\rho^2(t);\theta'(t)=c\ne 0\ .$$I assume $\rho(t)\ne 0$, or at least that $\rho$ vanishes only at isolated points, so $\theta'$ has a constant sign (except for isolated points, in fact the sign is the sign of $c\ne 0$). So $\theta$ is a strictly monotone function of class $\mathcal C^1$, since we already write the derivative, and maybe tacitly assume $\theta'$ continuous. Then locally there is an inverse, in physics, it's written $t=t(\theta)$. Now consider the composition of $\rho=\rho(t)$ with $t=t(\theta)$.

Thanks, now it's completely clear to me what is happening (mathematically speaking).
